# Knockout Image Not display while binding image and text at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

The below knockout binding never display the image.

```
  <p data-bind="text: $data.Title, attr:{onClick: 'variableName.CollapseExpandCustom.ToggleSection(\''+$data.Hsim+'\')'} " class="primaryCaseHeader"><img src="~/Images/Collapse.png" /></p>
```

I can see only the text.The image never shows.

Can anyone please help me how to show image and text at the same time.

Comment: consider marking it as answer/upvote . cheers

Answer (score 1):

well your are trying to override image content as it is placed between two `<p>` tags as `text` binding of `p` will override it

Workaround would be use data-bind on `<span>` tags .

view :

```
<p> <span data-bind="text: $data.Title, attr:{onClick: 'variableName.CollapseExpandCustom.ToggleSection(\''+$data.Hsim+'\')'} " class="primaryCaseHeader"></span><img src="~/Images/Collapse.png" /></p>
```

Now it will display image and text side by side .

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25893/)**