# How to display images and text using knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm learning more about knockout.js. I want to add images to my text data, and display the correct one based on the image link provided in the array with it's matching data. I only want one set to show at a time, so in other words it replaces the data. I don't quite grasp how the data binding stuff works just yet, and how everything displays. I'm stumbling my way through figuring it out.

What I sort of have figured out is the text part, but I'm lost on adding images based on the sets below.

Here's a short example of my data:

```
 const story = 

  //-------------------------------Initiate Chat
  {"1":{"text":"Pick a chat",
  "image":"http://placekitten.com/300/200",
  "choices":[{"choiceText":"Pick This","storyLink":"2"},{"choiceText":"no pick this","storyLink":"3"},{"choiceText":"nono this one","storyLink":"4"},{"choiceText":"dont pick this","storyLink":"5"},]},
  
   //-------------------------------Chat 1 test
  "2":{"text":"Kittens",
  "image":"https://placekitten.com/300/100",
  "choices":[{"choiceText":"Oops. Scared them.","storyLink":"3"}]},

  "3":{"text":"They are no longer scared",
  "image":"https://placekitten.com/300/100",
  "choices":[{"choiceText":"Poor things.","storyLink":"3"}]},
  
}
```

An example of working code would help me the most. I keep getting "Unable to Process Binding" Error when I have tried figuring it out. I can't seem to find specific examples where the images are being called along with other data like text as shown above. I appreciate the help!

For example: [Knockout Image Not display while binding image and text at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957232/knockout-image-not-display-while-binding-image-and-text-at-same-time)

this sort of answers my question but I'm not sure how to do it with an array. Should I be using a forEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to introduce some *view models* that make it easier to work with your story format.

In the example below, I created two:

- `StoryVM`

  - tracks the currently active section and returns its details
- `ChoiceVM`

  - adds an `onClick` handler that sets the active story to each choice,
  - takes the storyLink and looks up the corresponding image in the data

Once you have your image urls properly mapped between the choices and the main story chunks, you can use the `attr: { src }` binding to apply it to an image.

To prevent broken images when no src is available, I've wrapped the `<img>` tag in an `if` binding.

```js
const StoryVM = (model, startId) => {
  const activeStoryId = ko.observable(startId);

  const activeStory = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    const data = model[activeStoryId()]

    return {
      ...data,
      choices: data.choices.map(ChoiceVM)
    };
  });

  const ChoiceVM = ({
    choiceText,
    storyLink,
  }) => {
    return {
      image: storyModel[storyLink]?.image,
      text: choiceText,
      onClick: () => {
        activeStoryId(storyLink);
      }
    }
  }


  return activeStory;
}

const storyModel = {"1":{"text":"Pick a chat","image":"http://placekitten.com/300/200","choices":[{"choiceText":"Pick This","storyLink":"2"},{"choiceText":"no pick this","storyLink":"3"},{"choiceText":"nono this one","storyLink":"4"},{"choiceText":"dont pick this","storyLink":"5"}]},"2":{"text":"Kittens","image":"https://placekitten.com/300/100","choices":[{"choiceText":"Oops. Scared them.","storyLink":"3"}]},"3":{"text":"They are no longer scared","image":"https://placekitten.com/200/100","choices":[{"choiceText":"Poor things.","storyLink":"3"}]}};

ko.applyBindings({
  story: StoryVM(storyModel, "1")
});
```

```css
.Choices {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.Choice {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="with: story">
  <!-- ko if: image -->
  <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }">
  <!-- /ko -->

  <h2 data-bind="text: text"></h2>

  <div data-bind="foreach: choices" class="Choices">
    <div class="Choice">
      <!-- ko if: image -->
      <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }">
      <!-- /ko -->
      <button data-bind="click: onClick, text: text"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm excited to play with this. Super Helpful!

Comment: I have another question related to the way you set this up now that I have it working. If I wanted to create a function that calls the text in the data set and get it to start typing it (for example I have a timer function) how would I get it to do that without using a click/event? In an old version was able to say "arrayname[0]" and it would jump there when the timer ran out. I have tried changing activeStoryID to the corresponding chat but it doesn't "start" that chat so I am missing something.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. Can you show me the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Sure! Here's a Snippit. The function here is called after the timer runs out. This works just fine.

`setTimeout(wakeUp, 1000); 

function wakeUp()
{

  console.log("wakeup");
 activeStory = 3
  console.log(activeStory);
  
}
`
What it does right now, like in your example is a click binding activates changing the data from one set to another. I want to do that in this function, but I'm not sure what I need to change, or tell it to do in order for it to call it. I thought changing Active Story would do that. 

@user3297291

Does this make more sense?

Comment: To update an observable value, you write `activeStory(3)`, and **not** `activeStory = 3`. To read its value, you write `activeStory()`, and not `activeStory`. So: `activeStory(3); console.log(activeStory())`. See [this section of the docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh. Thank you for explaining that! I figured I was messing up the syntax from it. I confused myself reading the documentation. I'm still a pretty new coder so I appreciate the extra hand. 

@user3297291

Answer (score 1):

You use the  tag with the `attr` knockout binding to display images.  Example:

```
<img data-bind="attr: {src: 'https://placekitten.com/300/100'}">
```

See this working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/martlark/9v028d4z/34/

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing, thank you!